# How to persist a specific document offline

Tags: firebase, google-cloud-firestore

Using firebase,
I have a collection of users, I dont want to persist all users offline for every account but only for that specific users account - is this possible?

I read another answer saying that firebase dictates this and i have no control over it. I have my doubts about that as it seems like a fairly common use case

Comment: I'm not clear as to what you mean by:  "collection of users" (is this a Firestore document collection?),  "persist all users offline" (do you mean "documents"?), and "only for that specific users account" (is there some type of mapping/ownership of documents to the currently logged in user?)

Comment: I have a collection full of users and would like to persist one specific document corresponding to that user on their browser

Answer (score 2):

The most important part of Doug's answer is "...anything your app reads...".  The Firestore offline persistence cache DOES NOT fetch all, or even a significant part, or even *ANY* of your database until you execute read or write operations.  If your app only reads the authorized user's documents, only those documents will be in your cache.

*IF* you are fetching *all* user documents for each user's app, you *really* need to ask yourself "Why?!?" - especially that is in-and-of-itself a security problem.

Answer (score 1):

If you are referring to [Firestore's offline persistence cache](https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/manage-data/enable-offline), it's true that you don't have specific control over what it caches.  It will cache anything that your app reads, and store it for as long as it sees fit.

If you have specific caching needs that are not met by the Firestore SDK, you should consider disabling the cache and implement something yourself.

Comment: Ahh okay thats a shame. Is there any service that will sync a local and remote database

Comment: There's a lot more requirements I'd want to know about your app.  Why not allow caching of whatever user records get pulled down by the app?  Are you planning on using Firestore cache at all?  What is the purpose of this persistence?  Is there sensitive information in that document (e.g. PII or PHI or PCI or .... ?)

Answer (score 0):

One solution would be to store the user’s data in the [browser local storage](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window/localStorage). You can do that by using the [`onAuthStateChanged`](https://firebase.google.com/docs/auth/web/manage-users#get_the_currently_signed-in_user) observer:

```
firebase.auth().onAuthStateChanged(function(user) {
  if (user) {
     db.collection("users").doc(user.uid).get()
     .then(snap => {
        localStorage.setItem('userData', JSON.stringify(snap.data()));
     });
  } else {
    // No user is signed in.
  }
});
```